# Is the Amount of an Association Rule's Elements a Frequent Itemsets?

Tags: data-mining, apriori

While generating the association rules for the frequent itemset, is it necessary to maintain the cardinality of the frequent itemset? For example: if the frequent itemset is {a,b,c,d,e}, should the rules for X->Y be generated in such a way that |X| + |Y| = |frequent itemset|?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the amount of an association rule's elements is automatically a frequent itemset itself.

an association rule is obtained from a frequent itemset. every frequent itemset's item is a frequent item. and every combination of frequent itemset's items is again a frequent itemset itself. otherwise, a frequent itemset wouldn't be a frequent itemset.

an association rule consists of a frequent itemset's items and/or combinations of the frequent itemset's items. therefore, the elements of an association rule are frequent items and/or combination of the frequent itemset's items.

hence, the elements' amount of an association rule are a frequent itemset itself because it's extracted from a frequent itemset and all items or combinations of the items of a frequent itemset are frequent items or frequent itemsets itself.

e.g. every item `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` of the frequent itemset `{a, b, c, d, e}` is a frequent item. every item's combination `{a, b}`, `{a, c}`, `{a, d}`, ..., `{d, e}` of the frequent itemset `{a, b, c, d, e}` is a frequent itemset. every amount of an association rule's elements are frequent items or frequent itemsets. therefore, the amount `{a, b, c, d}` of the asscoiation rule `{a, b} => {c, d}` extracted from the frequent itemset `{a, b, c, d, e}` is an frequent itemset.